# Which standard defines CAT6?

Tags: cat6

I`m trying to figure out more information about CAT6 UTP cable in order to make a good desicion on what to purchase.

What is the max resistance in Ohm per 100 meter as defined in the standard? Also, which standard defines CAT6?

I have the following options for inner conductor size (0,57mm or 0,51mm) both pure copper.

Would 0.51mm suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as we don't know what you are planning to do with it, I usually just buy whatever suits me without looking up the specifics (for gigabit LAN at least, if you're going for 10 Gbits or whatever, you have to be sure the length and cable types, like CAT6a for 100m/90m 10GBASE-T).

[Cat6 specification](http://www.rm-electrical.com/technical/cable-cat6-cable-specification/)

> (Cable length: 100m)Characteristic Impedance(Zo): 85~115Ω (1~250 MHz)
>   DC. Resistance Capacitance Unbalance: 5% Pair-to-Ground Capacitance
>   Unbalance: 330 pF/100m Max. Conductor Resistance: 14.00Ω/100m 20o Max.
>   Mutual Capacitance: 5.6nF/m Max. Spark Test: 2.5kV Nominal Velocity of
>   Propagation (NVP): 69%

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I`m actually just interested if it meets the standard (just to expand my knowledge of CAT6)
My shop says that 0,57mm has an Impedance of 7.8Ω per 100 meter.

If I understand your quote well, 14Ω/100m is the limit. In other words, if the Ω/100m does not exceed 14, I should be able to maintain 10gbit over 55 meter (given that there is no alien cross talk)

Is that right?

Comment: @JurGroen I wouldn't assume that 10GE will work unless the cable is certified category 6. There are tight tolerances for insertion loss, twisting, and so on.

Comment: cat6a can reach up to 100m in 10GE, cat6e around 50m (55m I think), always under the right conditions, of course. (No too tight bends, proper wiring, etc.)